# UpdatePanel trigger: Could not find an event named 'OnRowCommand'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

I want the `OnRowCommand` event of the `GridView` to not perform a full postback on a `ErrorLinkButton` click.  So I wrapped the control in an update panel and added an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for `OnRowCommand`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataSourceMappingGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Index" ClientIDMode="Static" OnRowCommand="DataSourceMappingGridView_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="DataSourceMappingGridView_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ErrorUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DataSourceMappingGridView" EventName="OnRowCommand" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ErrorTextLinkButton" CommandName="Errors" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Index") %>' runat="server" Text='View Errors' /> 
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But I get the following error:

> Could not find an event named 'OnRowCommand' on associated control
>   'DataSourceMappingGridView' for the trigger in UpdatePanel
>   'ErrorUpdatePanel'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The event is called `RowCommand` not `OnRowCommand`

Replace

```
EventName="OnRowCommand"
```

with

```
EventName="RowCommand"
```

and it should work